# TokenMismatchException in laravel 5.2 ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

i am getting token mismatch exception every thing is seem correct.

this is my view code

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
<div class="bg"></div>
<div class="login-sec clearfix">

    <h1 class="lg-logo">YOU ARE JUST ONE STEP AHEAD</h1>
    <div class="login-box clear">

        <form id="websiteform" action="#">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <div class="col-md-12 form-field">
                <label for="">Project Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="project" id="project">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 form-field">
                <label for="">Website URL</label>
                <input type="url" name="website_url" id="website_url">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 form-field">
                <button type="submit" class="btn-green btn-large">Add Your Website</button>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
@stop
```

and form source head section and footer is

```
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title></title>
<meta name="csrf-token" content="4ryCSznz0mPSBcwXvbmZZHkZGcxZpyDy2dQ1VAoc" />
<link href="http://localhost:8080/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

```
 <script src="http://localhost:8080/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8080/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8080/js/main.js"></script>
```

and my ajax call in main.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
$('#websiteform').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var pro=$('#project').val();
    var url=$('#website_url').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "project_save",
        data:  {project: pro, url: url},
        success: function(data)
        {
            if(data.success==false)
            {
             alert(data.error);
            }
            else{
                window.location =  "dashboard";
            }
        },
        error:function(){}
    });
});
});
```

and route and controller function

```
 Route::post('/project_save','WebsiteController@project_save');
  public function project_save()
{
    if(Request::ajax()){

        $validator = Validator::make(Request::all(), [
            'project' => 'required|max:255',
            'url' => 'required',
        ]);
        if($validator->fails()){
            return Response::json(['success'=>false,'error'=>$validator->errors()->toArray()]);
        }

        $Website = new Website;
        $Website->project_name = Request::get('project');
        $Website->website_url = Request::get('url');
        $Website->user_id = Auth::id();
        $Website->save();
        return Response::json(['success'=>true]);
    }

}
```

this is my code and i am getting tokenmismatach exeption.

Comment: Remove input hidden field csrf_token and check

Comment: That field is not necessary, but it wouldn't break an AJAX call

Comment: i removed but same issue..

Comment: Your real header template has csrf_token() method, not the static token like you are showing here, right?

Comment: @DenisMysenko i did not understand ,sorry i am new in laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php`, add this code to function `tokensMatch`:

```
if ($request->ajax()) {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You are proposing to disable checks, not to fix his particular case

Comment: Its not correct answer bro because whenever the request is ajax it will return true rite?

Comment: Yep, skip all request for ajax

Comment: If you are doing that why need csrf protection?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$_token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
$.post( 'myurl', { param1: $param1, param2: $param2, _token: $_token })
  .done(function( data )
{
    console.log('Done!');
});
```

Comment: no it does not help..same issue token missmatch... :-(

Comment: Check this and let me know

Comment: Remove $.ajaxSetup({}) function and keep there

Comment: Try this and let me know

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want CSRF protection for a particular url then you can add the urls in  `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php` like this

```
protected $except = [
    "project_save"
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Carefully do a check on the following :

I had a similar issue and it was an easy fix.

Add this in your HTML meta tag area :

```
 <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then under your JQuery reference, add this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
      });
  </script>
```

If you are using the HTML form submit (not AJAX) then you need to put :

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

inside your form tags.